# How to iterate through DataTable cells

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get the count of all cells in a DataTable, how can i do this ? I need this to verify that my 2 tables has the same cell amount before inserting data into a database.

Comment: `var nCells = dt.Rows.Count * dt.Columns.Count;`

Comment: @CodeIgnoto Yes, i am using open.xml to read a excel sheet but this sdk ignors the empty rows. So i wanna check if the excel file datatable has the same count of cells as the database datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable(), dt2 = new DataTable();

    // define and populate your tables

    int count1 = dt1.Columns.Count * dt1.Rows.Count;
    int count2 = dt2.Columns.Count * dt2.Rows.Count;

    bool verified = count1 == count2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
 foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
 {
   foreach (DataColumn col in tbl.Columns)
   {
     object cellData = row[col];
   }
 }
```

Comment: This does not get the count of all cells in a DataTable as the OP requested, it just loops the cells.

Comment: yes i know, i answered how to iterate through DataTable cells